# Is it possible to hit Gore Harrier type enemies while they're hovering above?

Tags: diablo-iii

In several areas of Act 2 (Desolate Sands comes to mind) there are flying enemies that seem to circle above and swarm just out of reach before dropping into battle.

I've tried throwing the skills I have on my build at them, to no effect.  I have to wait for them to descend if I want to do damage.  If there's other enemies in the area, they tend to follow me and attack at inopportune times.

Are there any skills that can injure these type of enemies before they descend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They aren't actual enemies until they swoop down.  I've used the monk skill Cyclone Strike, which pulls nearby enemies in to you, and they never respond until they begin their swooping animation.  About halfway through the animation they will get sucked in, and can be attacked.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak as to "any" skills, but I am reasonably certain you can't kill them until they descend as I've tried quite a range of skills myself.  Their Lore entry also implies that there's nothing that can be done about them until they swoop:

> It is easy to focus on the dangerous foes one may encounter on the
>   ground, but the blood hawks rule the skies with terrible ferocity.
>   These crimson-winged birds will wait until their prey is at a
>   disadvantage, then swoop down to attack. **Watch for their shadows on
>   the nearby terrain, and be prepared to flee quickly.**